# Размер ссылок в java

Tags: java, примитивы

На собеседовании столкнулась с таким вопросом:

> сколько места в памяти java занимает примитив?

Т.е., если, например, у нас есть переменная `int abc = 5`, где-то в памяти должно храниться ее название (переменная может называться 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa', или хоть размером с длину алфавита).

В общем, вопрос ставился как-то так: где и какая информация хранится о примитиве, и сколько места она занимает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имена нужны человеку, после прохождения стадии трансляции в байт-код, в нём уже нет никаких имен длиною в алфавит и в память грузится именно байт-код. В общем не стоит думать, что ваш текст напрямую находит отображение в итоговой программе.

Есть описание типа, есть ссылка на участок в памяти (вместо имени генерируется транслятором) и есть само значение в памяти. Первые два строго не регламентированы спецификацией и могут зависеть от JVM и тема достаточно сложная (https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-layout), а вот само значение в памяти у примитивов [имеет определенное значение и описано спецификацией](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Можно еще подумать о хранении в стеке или куче. Неизвестно, на какой уровень вы проходили собеседование, но возможно от вас требовалась только эта табличка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все поняла, спасибо за ответ! Мне кажется, от меня хотели услышать, что в итоге у нас остаются описание типа, ссылка на участок в памяти и само значение

Comment: 1 бит? Не верю.

Comment: @Qwertiy да легко, главное "правильно" мерить: [This data type represents one bit of information, but its "size" isn't something that's precisely defined.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю прочесть две ссылки

1. https://habr.com/ru/post/134102/
2. https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/630-primitivnihe-tipih-v-java--ne-takie-uzh-oni-i-primitivnihe

Собственно хорошо описано разница между ссылочными переменными и примитивами. Надеюсь будет полезно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Буду изучать)